# My page has their own cookie path, and they aren't connect to the index page. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

When I click to allow the cookie on the blog page, then it has its own path. After that, I go back to the index page it asks for a cookie again.

(But, if I click allow on the index page, the cookie could connect to every page.)
[enter image description here][1]

This happens when I click allow on the index page and blog page. (It has 2 cookies and the same name, but it would record in a different path)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjlI4.png

````
acceptBtn = cookieBox.querySelector(".consent_buttons button");

acceptBtn.onclick = ()=>{
    document.cookie = "Geek-Cookies=GEEKGENTH; max-age"+60*60*24*30;
    if(document.cookie) { //if the above cookie had set
        cookieBox.classList.add("hide");
    }else {
        alert("Cookie can't be set!");
    }
}
let checkCookie = document.cookie.indexOf("Geek-Cookies=GEEKGENTH");
checkCookie != -1 ? cookieBox.classList.add("hide"): cookieBox.classList.remove("hide");```

Thank you in advance,
````

Comment: Add `path=/` to your cookie string (they use the current path by default)

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you very much, that's help me!!!